# Docker communication between containers localhost on mac

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, containers, docker-network

There are 10 services in my development environment running on individual ports on my localhost, communicating using localhost:port with each other.

I want to push the same setup to docker containers but on doing so, the services are communicating to their own localhost within the container and failing to connect to other service. I tried with [network_mode: host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) in this case the services are able to connect to each other but on the other-hand am not able to access them from my Mac machine using localhost:port as host network-mode is only supported in Linux.

I can not change the localhost to `host.docker.internal` or `gateway.docker.internal` as there are too many services where the changes has to be made also this is part of a larger team project hence can not take the risk of making changes to the codebase/config

Please help with any method for Mac where we can use the `network_mode: host` and still able to connect to the container from host or any other alternative to overcome the restriction of host network-mode

Here is a snippet of my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  config:
    container_name: Config
    image: node:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3026:3026
    expose:
      - 3026
    volumes:
      - ./configserver:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - node
      - alatheia/alatheia
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:3026/ping || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
  oauth:
    container_name: OAuth
    image: node:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3010:3010
    volumes:
      - ./oauth:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - node
      - app.js
    depends_on:
      config:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
  redis:
    container_name: Redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
  service1:
    container_name: Service1
    image: node:12.22.12
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    volumes:
      - ./service1:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - node
      - node/app
    depends_on:
      config:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
      oauth:
        condition: service_started
```

Comment: That's why those hostnames and ports should be configurable with environment variables. So you could use `gateway.docker.internal` and then set the variable to the same value for each service. The fact that they have localhost *hard coded*, is a code smell, IMO.

Comment: Even better you could use the container name or network alias to set up the communication, which would be the idiomatic way.

Comment: They are set to configurable for other environments like staging/uat/prod but not for development(localhost), if no env is passed it will take the localhost else it will take the format ```env-servicename.domainname```.

Comment: Then I would suggest using the networkalias aka compose service names as value for those env variables. Then you only publish the port of the thing that needs to be published. I.e. redis probably doesnt need to be exposed. As mentioned, that would be the idiomatic way.

Comment: In that case I have to setup my docker network for my domain name resolution, here it would loose connectivity to the DB hosted on cloud

Comment: Can you explain this more? I don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: As mentioned above on passing the environment variable the host name will be resolving to ```environment-servicename.domainname```, if I pass development as a variable then the hostname will be ```development-servicename.domainname```  which will point to the cloud, but not my internal docker network, let support change the domain name of my docker network to match the actual domain name, then I would loose the connectivity to DB as when running in local we connect to a DB hosted on cloud so that entire team has access to the same DB as other when working on local.

Comment: so you have an env variable, but by setting it the hostname is taken from a fixed set of hostnames? The idiomatic way would be to have an env variable called `MONGO_URI` for example. And that one can be set to any value. So I think the way you have it there is a code smell. Hard coded host named are not good for a number of reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247236/discussion-between-sarbesh-sarkar-and-the-fool).